# fixed positioning with a drawer

Tags: css, css-position

on [this site](Http://gioventu.nyc) i have the side nav `position: fixed` and it works fine, until someone clicks on "my cart" which then has the cart appear in a drawer, thus pushing down the main container.

however, the side nav isn't being pushed down and it looks like this. you can see the logo is working right as a comparison and the nav should be below it, but it's not. [image]

here's the CSS on the sidebar currently

```
#index #sidebar, #index-v2 #sidebar {
top: 100px;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
z-index: 99;
}
```

any idea how to get it to work so the sidebar pushed down when the container is active?

Answer (score 0):

As along as you have it set to position:fixed it will always remain right there. If you want it to move down when the drawer opens I would suggest placing the side nav inside the main container and setting it to float:left or position:absolute instead of position:fixed.

If you use the latter option you should set the main container to position:relative

Comment: thanks for your help. my only questions is im confused because the logo is acting correctly (staying fixed but then pushing down when the container is enabled). is there a reason my sidebar can't do the same?